# Dynamically store the API data

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I have to extract data from API's and return the report with the required info.
For eg:

```
request_data = {'url1 : https://abcd.com','url2 : https://dfgh.com','url3 : https://hjkl.com',column : (name,Ecode,salary,status)}

x1 =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

x2 = '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "Ecode":"4567"}'

x3 = '{ "name":"John", "salary":30k, "Status":"Yes"}'
```

here request_data is the get request that I receive through a messaging queue and x1,x2,x3 are the values which we get after running the get request from python. Once we get the data I convert it to pandas dataframe and use pandas dataframe merge to create a new dataframe.

But the number of url's wont be 3 in the get request. It would be 2,5,1, etc. So we cannot explicitly name the variables as x1,x2,x3 as the variables to store data.

I want to make code more dynamic so that any number of url request we get from message queue, we need to get data from those url and create a new dataframe with the required columns.

Can someone please help me here or point to some reference link.

Comment: you could create an array of multiple data frames. iterate though all the responses, create a new df and append it to the master list.

Answer (score 2):

You could start by creating an empty dataframe called cumulative_df in which you could collect the responses of the different API calls.

Then, loop through the list of URLs; within the loop, for each URL:

1. Make the API call (e.g., by using the requests library).
2. Convert the JSON response to a dataframe (e.g., by using [pandas.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html))
3. Add the dataframe created by json_normalize to cumulative_df (e.g., by using [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html))

This could be done for any number of URLs in your list.

Edit: if the dataframes cannot be concatenated/appended, you could use a counter to name the variable and assign the dataframe to it inside of the loop. At first, 'x'+str(i) will result in x1. Then increment the counter by 1, and the next instance of the loop would create x2, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for you response. In my case i cant simply append the data. I have to use merge. For eg: 3rd url data might have 50 entries while 1st url have only 20 entries. Now I need to get only 20 entries in my final dataframe and data from 3rd url needs to be picked for only those 20 entries which we get from 1st url. Basically the join that we do in sql.

Comment: In that case, initialize a counter before the loop. Then, inside the loop assign each dataframe to a new variable by concatenating the file name and the counter. For example, if the counter is i and the file name is x, use 'x'+str(i). Then, increment the counter by 1.

Comment: can you please share a sample code for this. Like if I want to save the data as df1,df2,df3 and so on.. how can I achieve?

Comment: @SampathShanbhag, can you please clarify which part of the process you are trying to automate (e.g., the API calls, the dataframe merges)? What does your data look like when you have two items or five? What output do you expect?

Comment: I have created a new question. Please refer  this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70502408/merge-the-dataframes-dynamically