# Merge the dataframes dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am extracting data from API's to generate a report. But the number of API's are dynamic for each report. It can be 1,2,3,5 etc. Once we get the data , we need to store the data as dataframe, to generate report on required columns having a common column in all the  dataframes.

for example:

dataframe1:

```
  emp_id  salary
1  5642    50k
2  7865    75k
3  9876    30k
4  1874    60k
```

dataframe2:

```
  emp_id  Name   DOJ
1  5642   Jack  23DEC
2  9876   Sam   07APR
```

dataframe3:

```
  emp_id  Designation    Status
1  5642    Developer    Available
2  7865    Testing      Available
3  9876     BA          Resigned
4  7590    Developer    Resigned
5  4765    Developer    Available
```

Now how to store these data to a variable so that we can use them for data manipulation using pandas. Since number of API urls are dynamic.

Required Output:

```
emp_id    Name   Designation   Status
1  5642   Jack    Developer   Available
2  7865   NAN    Testing      Available
3  9876   Sam      BA         Available
4  1874   NAN      NAN          NAN
```

Comment: Where are the `salary` and `DOJ` columns in the output?

Comment: @mozway along with API's we get the required columns name that need to be in final dataframe.

Comment: Here you don't have symmetrical operations. You're performing an outer merge on df2 but inner on df3. That needs to be defined somehow

Comment: @mozway Got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` function. If `df_list` is your list of data frames then you can merge an arbitrary number of data frames by a key, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on = 'emp_id'), df_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But your solution gives output for ID 5642 and 9876. The other two rows will be skipped.